# Update database field with array in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Again I find myself at the mercy of the stackoverflow community!

I've gone over to use CodeIgniter for my PHP projects and it's been a breeze so far, hoever I've gotten stuck trying to update a database field with some post data.

My array is the usual: array(name => value, name => value, name => value);
which again is populated from the submitted $_POST data.

Similarly to the array, I have a database table with 2 fields: **setting** and **value**, where the names under **setting** corresponds to the array keys and **value** to the array keys' value.

(Did I explain that right?)

Nonetheless, I've been trying for a little while now to get this to work as it should, but, I'm really just waving my hands around in the dark.

I hope some of you bright minds out there can help me with this annoying issue!

**Edit:**

Thanks to everyone who replied! I managed to produce the result that I wanted with the following code:

```
    foreach ($form_data as $key => $val)
    {
        $this->db->where ('setting', $key);
        $this->db->set ('value', $val);
        $this->db->update ('recruitment');
    }
```

Now, I tried following up with this by adding:

```
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() >= '1') { return true; }
    return false;
```

To my model, and

```
        if ($this->RecruitmentSettings->Update($form_data) == TRUE)
        {
            redirect('recruitment/success');
        }
```

to my controller, but it's not working as expected at all. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of questions here. Do you already have values in the database and you want to update them? Or do you want to put in new data every time? The answer depends on that.

What you want is the `insert_batch()` or `update_batch()` methods of the active record class (if that's what you're using for the db).

```
foreach($post_array as $key => $value)
{
    $settings[] = array(
        'setting' => $key,
        'value' => $value
    );
}

$this->db->insert_batch('your_db_table', $settings);
```

OR, for updates:

```
$this->db->update_batch('your_db_table', $settings, 'setting');
```

You could do a query to check for settings and do `insert_batch` or `update_batch` depending on if there are results. If you wanted to insert every time, you could delete the rows in the table before you do the insert. I wouldn't do that without a transaction, however.

Comment: I tried this method, but it produced the error _"You must specify an index to match on for batch updates."_ which I really don't understand. Hmm.

Comment: See http://localhost/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update. `update_batch` takes a third param which is the 'where' clause... (the index to match on). In this case, set it to 'setting': `$this->db->update_batch('your_db_table', $settings, 'setting');`

Comment: That's it! It worked perfectly. Together with the affected_rows() code I added above, it's the perfect solution to my needs.

Comment: I just realized I copied the link from my local copy of the CI user guide! Oops! Correct link: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update

Answer (score 0):

So you want to store the array data in the database? You could do this

Model

```
foreach ($data as $key => $item)
{
      $this->db->set ('setting', $key);
      $this->db->set ('value', $item);
      $this->db->insert ('table_name');
}
return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0);
```

Controller

```
if ($this->RecruitmentSettings->Update($form_data))
{

 redirect('recruitment/success');
}
else
{
     echo "error";
}
```

Comment: This won't work because you're not using an object. You need to do foreach($data as $key => $value) and then use $key for setting and $value for value. See my answer. The arrow notation doesn't work for arrays AFAIK. You'd get the error "attempting to access property of a non-object" or something.

Comment: Actually, if you want it to work, you need to do sub arrays within the main array. I.e. `array( array('name'=>name,'value'=>value), array('name'=>name,'value'=>value))` etc. with the way your code is written currently. But then you could just use `foreach($array as $key => $value)`

Comment: no you dont need to do sub-arrays. if you have a simple array and do a 'foreach' - php splits the simple array for each item. I just tried it to confirm - it works